# using btrfs features to rapidly and efficiently combine large files

Tags: linux, file-management, btrfs, deduplication

My aim is to use btrfs features to combine several 3GB files into a single 9GB file without producing substantial i/o nor using additional disk space. If this works for this set of data, I plan to implement this in my pipeline and easily save a terabyte of disk space.

My previous attempts:

Normally I `cat` these smaller 3GB files to a single file, producing a lot of i/o. On btrfs I tried duperemove on these files to save disk space. This which works only for the first proportion of the larger file, effectively saving me 3GB out of 9GB (which is nice).

A better method with the same result would be to use `cp --reflink=always` on the first file, and then append the others. This will be substantially faster and skips the time consuming deduplication step, yet I still produce 6GB of i/o and additional disk space.

I am now looking for a way to use btrfs features to combine these files as if they are concatenated on to each other yet referring to the original extent in the b-tree. (if my understanding of btrfs is correct)

thanks for your consideration

Comment: `btrfs` is a filesystem, not a tool to combine files. Or you mean that you have three files, and on the top of them you want to create a filesystem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Indeed btrfs is not a tool, I see how my question can be read that way. I will shortly clarify: btrfs is a filesystem which allows for advanced edits like deduplication. These and other features are possible due to file extent trees, backreferencing etc. I hope to establish a method to use these underlying btrfs mechanisms to create a new file of which the content is identical to mutiple currently existing files without the typical i/o. Concluding, I am not acctually using btrfs to do so although its underlying mechanisms are essential for such an undertaking.

Comment: `cp --reflink` works fine on `btrfs` (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219280/why-does-cp-r-reflink-always-perform-a-standard-copy-on-a-btrfs-filesystem)), but it serves a bit different purpose. Of course if you know in advance that the data is the same, then use it. But `btrfs` (or better say, a special utility) can run the de-duplication process post-factum (see [btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication)). I've never used that utility, however I can imagine it will take a while to find duplicate blocks across whole filesystem.